# IDEA. Console tab is hidden. How to fix?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use IDEA. And i can build my project. And "Run" is enabled. But!

When i run my project IDEA do nothing...

How to fix it?

## **UPDATE**

`package kernel;`

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      System.out.println("Im here!");

```
  JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("sfdfds");
  jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
  jFrame.setSize(200,200);
  jFrame.setVisible( true );
```

}
}

I want to see form and text in the output stream. If you worked in Eclipse or Netbeans, that you should remember, that there is a console tab.

Comment: When you say 'Run' enabled - do you mean the Green play button in the top menu bar? and when you say the Console tab is hidden - which Console tab is this?  I can see a Console tab in my Debug pane - is this the one you mean? or are you talking about the actual Run pane?

Comment: Yes about green button in the top menu bar.

Comment: To the left of the Green Run button, there is a drop down which is the configuration for the thing you're running.  What if you click on that configuration drop down and choose 'Edit Configurations'.  Does everything look okay in the window that pops up?

Comment: Just as an FYI, I ran the code you pasted above and I had the frame appear and the text "Im here!" appear in the "Run" pane.  I'm using 9.0.3 (build 95.429)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0gj73O7392sZGMzYWYxYzEtMTI1ZC00YWFkLTgxMzItZGFjZDMzMjA4ZjUw&hl=en

Comment: :) it's greate. But, i can't see Run pane. How to set visible it???

Comment: Window -> Tool Windows -> Run is not enabled...

Comment: I'm sure this will make no difference but what if you uncheck all the checkboxes in the "Edit Configuration" popup except for the "Make" checkbox, click OK and then click the green Run button?

Comment: It seems like your setting isn't right, did you configure you Application run settings?

Answer (score 0):

Which version/build number of Idea do you use?

**UPDATE:** I just have tested your application with your version of IntelliJ Idea with default settings and JDK 1.6 x64, and I have no problems with.

Have you searched [Jetbrains Issue Tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/) for this issue before posting here?

Comment: How to restore default settings?

Comment: Do you need all checkboxes you have settend in run settings?